# Troca de video Jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, vídeo

Não to conseguindo fazer com que após clicar o botão, trocasse o vídeo
Eu queria que o vídeo trocasse no de cima, mas aparece 2 após clicar no botão...

```js
function setvideo(src) {
    document.getElementById('div_video').innerHTML = '<video autoplay controls id="video_ctrl" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"><source         src="'+src+'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video autoplay id="video_ctrl" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button onClick="setvideo('video.mp4');">Video1</button>
<button onClick="setvideo('video2.mp4');">Video2</button>
<div id="div_video"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No teu HTML tens esta estrutura:

```
body
 |-video
 |-button
 |-button
 |-div#div_video
```

A tua função JavaScript está a substituir o conteúdo da div com ID `div_video`.

Se o que pretendes é substituir o video original por um novo então deves colocar esse video **dentro** da `div#div_video` para ser apagado/substituído e ficar assim:

```
body
 |-button
 |-button
 |-div#div_video
    |-video
```

ou seja:

```
<button onClick="setvideo('video.mp4');">Video1</button>
<button onClick="setvideo('video2.mp4');">Video2</button>
<div id="div_video">
    <video autoplay id="video_ctrl" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7bhe7k8r/**

Comment: Muito Obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Quando está chamando o `setVideo()`, está modificando o HTML direto do `<div id="div_video">`. A sua página, porém, originalmente não tem nenhum HTML dentro do `<div>`, e um tag de `<video>` lá em cima.

O primeiro vídeo é do primeiro `<video>` de lá em cima, e o segundo é o que aperece depois de chamar o `setVideo()`.

Se você quer que aparece um vídeo primeiro, sem ter que clicar numa botão, e sem definir o `<video>` em HTML, poderia usar o `onload` assim:

```
<button onclick="setvideo('video.mp4');">Video1</button>
<button onclick="setvideo('video2.mp4');">Video2</button>
<div id="div_video" onload="setvideo('video.mp4');">
</div>
```